# Creating custom objects that include custom objects Powershell

Tags: powershell

Essentially i'm trying to store an object and some values inside of another object.  Is this possible?  I'm trying to do it this way:

```
$testingobject = New-Object PSOBject
$testingobject2 = New-Object PSOBject 

$testingobject2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "test" -value "test"
$testingobject  | Add-Member -MemberType MemberSet -name "test2" -Value $testingobject2
```

The error message is:

```
Add-Member : Cannot convert value "@{test=test}" to type 
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo]". Error: "Cannot 
convert the "@{test=test}" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type 
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo]"."
At line:1 char:19
+ $testingobject  | Add-Member -MemberType MemberSet -name "test2" -Value $testing ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Member], PSInvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastConstructorException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand
```

How should i be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new object with your properties, you could easily do it using the `New-Object` cmdlet and the `-Property` parameter, to which you can pass a hashtable with your properties.

```
$myObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Property1 = "MyValue"
    Property2 = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        SubProperty1 = "AnotherValue"
    }
}
```

If you want to use `Add-Member` to add a new property, you should probably use the `NoteProperty` member type. You can read more about the available types on the documentation about the [PSMemberTypes Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.psmembertypes%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
$myObject | Add-Member -Name Property3 -MemberType NoteProperty -Value (New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    SubProperty2 = "YetAnotherValue"
})
```

To test this object, we could use the following:

```
$myObject.Property1
$myObject.Property2.SubProperty1
$myObject.Property3.SubProperty2
```

This will yield the following output:

> MyValue
>
> AnotherValue
>
> YetAnotherValue

We could also replace one of the objects in a property with an object with other child properties, if we want:

```
$myObject.Property2 = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    SubProperty3 = "A fourth value"
}

$myObject.Property2.SubProperty3
```

Which would yield:

> A fourth value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just change "MemberSet" to "NoteProperty" in your last line.

If you're using PowerShell v2 or higher, you can do this in one line:

```
$testingobject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ test2 = (New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{test = "test"}) }
```